# How to trim characters from a string in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get record id by code in database. Problem is that many of codes in database are with line breaks or something else like:
"12545
"

I tried this queries, but it did not work, I only get ids that code has no line breaks

```
SELECT * FROM Firms WHERE REPLACE(Code,'/n/r','') = '302489977'

SELECT * FROM Firms WHERE TRIM(Code) = '302489977'
```

Comment: "line breaks or something else" does this mean line breaks and other odd characters, or that you don't know what the character is?

Comment: I don't know, because I see only line break

Comment: Can you identify the characters using `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY, [column])`?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @jarth they said they were using "mssql" but they accidentally tagged the question with [tag:mysql]. I believe Stack Overflow automatically tags virtually all "sql" questions with mysql unless you're careful to change the tags. I've edited the tags to replace mysql with [tag:sql-server].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult without seeing what your data structure is like, but something like this may work. CHAR13 and CHAR10 represent line breaks.

Specifically, CHAR(13) is carriage return and CHAR(10) is line feed.

```
Select Replace(Replace(@str,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
```

Comment: You probably have only Line Feeds, without the Carriage Return.

Comment: that'll be why my chained version didn't work then :( didn't consider that.

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE(Code,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')
```

maybe

Comment: the same. can't get results with breaks.

Comment: what are the characters actually stored in the database as ? i would assume they're not in there as actual characters \r\n but instead control chars

Comment: how to know that? when i copy that records from database management app i see only code with line break

Comment: as berty has said in his response 13 and 10 are normally carriage return and line break so that should (at least to me) have worked so my thought is as you're copying and pasting its not storing them in the actual db as those control characters, Sometimes also called the MS Word issue as it uses random characters some times for no reason so they get stored wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `LIKE`?

```
 SELECT * FROM Firms WHERE Code LIKE '%302489977%';
```

This will work if you can't have an id on multiple lines (that is to say on multiple lines) and if an other id can't be found in the code.

Comment: i am afraid this could lead to incorrect entries with similar codes :(

Comment: if your codes always have the same length is should be OK